# bootstrap datepicker beforeShowDay not working when called inside $.when().done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, datepicker

hello after ajax call to get calandar dates to show  in the Datapicker,i call a function to initialize datapicker with parameter array of dates... the problem is that  beforeShowDay  is not working. Note it works fine when called outside of $.when().done() but with already assigned dates by default not from db;

here function to inizialize datapicker :

```
function inizializeCalander(array){
    var format ="dd/mm/yyyy";
    var datesd = ['11/05/2020', '05/21/2020'];
    var date = new Date();
    var avaibleDates =array;
    var id_Dates = new Array();

    date.setDate(date.getDate());
    $('.pickerdate').datepicker({
        language: "it",
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + date.getDate(),
            year = date.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            if (day.length < 2) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }       

            var dmy = day +"-"+month+"-"+year;
            if (avaibleDates.includes(dmy)) {

                return {classes: 'highlight', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }else{
                return {classes: 'disabled', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }

         },
        startDate: date,
        autoclose:true,
        format: format,
        //daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3",
        datesDisabled:datesd,
        inline: true,
        todayHighlight: true,

    });
}
```

here is when inizializeClander is called :

```
$.when(getClanderDates()).done(function(ajax1Results){
   var array = new Array();
   array=ajax1Results;
   console.log(array);
   inizializeCalander(array);
});

//inizializeCalander(array);//if called outside it workd fine  but with already assigned dates by default not from db;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi might im late but you have to do this  in your function inizializeCalander:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate()); 
$('.pickerdate').datepicker('destroy');
$('.pickerdate').datepicker({ ......... code
```

Why? Because datapicker is already initialized before you call inizializeCalander(); as ajax call takes time so first you have to destroy it and then reinitilize it. Hope it works ;)